# error in i18n in activeadmin

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, yaml, activeadmin

i'm use the active activeAdmin in translate to Portuguese my source code file yaml:

```
"pt-PT":
  activerecord:
    models:
      position:
        one: "Posição"
        other: "Posições"
```

Trace:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError in Admin::PositionsController#index

incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/activeadmin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in join'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:intos'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:in content'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:in block in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:incollect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:incontent'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:inblock in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in collect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:in content'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:in block in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:incollect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:incontent'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:inblock in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in collect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:in content'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:in block in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:incollect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:incontent'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:inblock in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in collect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:in content'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/tag.rb:76:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/document.rb:25:in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:21:inblock in to_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:in collect'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/collection.rb:20:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:115:in content'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:135:into_s'
activeadmin (0.4.4) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:131:in to_str'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:56:injoin'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:56:in digest_body'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:26:incall'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:incall'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:incall'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:incall'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in call'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:incall'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:inblock in call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run765012194call948180406_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in _run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:inrun_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:incall'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:incall'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:incall_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:incall'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:incall'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:incall'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:incall'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:incall'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:inservice'
/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in service'
/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:inrun'
/home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

the error is caused by the use of special characters in both file yaml in database with someone can help me solve?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your editor save your files in UTF8 ?

If it's still doesn't work, try to add this line at the top of your file ( you're rigth, it's not usefull in yml file, just in rb files) : 
    # encoding: utf-8

Edit: with more configurations

Make sure that you have :

in your application.rb :

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

In your config/environment.rb :

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: my files are stored utf8, but I added the yaml does not work, the same error occurs, this code "# encoding: utf-8" is also to add to the admin files and models?

Comment: I removed all the lines with special characters in the database and no longer gives error but every time I create a new entry with special characters that page crashes.

Comment: I removed all the lines with special characters in the database and no longer gives error but every time I create a new entry with special characters that page crashes.

database.yml

development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: sqlexpress
  username: sa
  password: XXXXX
  encoding: utf8